# Django Tastypie custom model method

Tags: django, django-models, tastypie

I just start using Django with Tastypie in a Rest application with two models.

Parameters are snipped for brevity.

```
class Player(models.Model):

    pseudo = models.CharField(max_length=32, unique=True)

class Score(models.Model):

    level = models.IntegerField()
    score = models.IntegerField()
    player = models.ForeignKey(Player)
```

There can be multiple score for one player.
I can get all scores like this: */api/v1/score/*
But how can I retrieve the scores linked with a specific player?

How can I implement that?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [filtering](http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/resources.html#basic-filtering) on `/api/v1/score/` so you can use `/api/v1/player/?player=1` e.g.

```
class ScoreResource(ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        ...
        filtering = {'player':ALL_WITH_RELATIONS}
```

or you can use [ToManyField](http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/resources.html#reverse-relationships) to access scores as part of the player resource, something like:

```
class ScoreResource(ModelResource):
    ...

class PlayerResource(ModelResource):
    score = fields.ToManyField(ScoreResource, 'scores', full=True)
```

Then you will be able to access `/api/v1/player/1/` and will include the `ScoresResource`